# Dictionary in python takes in "None" value even when the value assigned is a list, how can I resolve this issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, logic

```
self.poss={0:[0],1:[0],2:[0],3:[0]}
z=self.possibilities[t]
self.poss[t]=current_path.append(z)
print(current_path)
current_path.pop()
print(";;;;;")
print(self.poss)
```

possibilities is a list from which z takes one value

***Output for the code above:**

```
[7, 12]
;;;;;
{0: None, 1: [0], 2: [0], 3: [0]*
```

what I wanted to do is this:

```
[7]
```

take 7 from the list, find possibilities(not relevant to question), lets say the possibilities come out as `[1,2,3]`
so then I want to create the following three lists:

```
[7,1]
[7,2]
[7,3]
```

Thank You for your help!

Comment: append method of list doesn't return anything. Append first then assign the value to dict.

Comment: Please, post [mre]. Assuming that `current_path` is a list, `current_path.append(z)` will be `None` (`list.append()` works inplace and retuns `None`)